# Why does socat behave differently when run from Jenkins job and from the terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, tcp, socat

**Aim**:
I'd like to establish a bidirectional serial connection over the network, i.e. have two character devices on different hosts, *h1*, which is a Jenkins slave, and *h2*, bound by a TCP connection. This is supposed to run as a part of Jenkins job. My tool of choice is `socat`.

**The problem**:
`socat` behaves erroneously when run from Jenkins. The job is a 'Freestyle' Jenkins project with just one build step - 'Execute shell':

```
#!/bin/bash -e
socat -x -d -d -d tcp:h2:54321 pty,link=/tmp/vmodem1,echo=0,raw,wait-slave
```

These steps reproduce the problem every time:

1. *h2*: Run TCP server

   `socat -x -d -d -d pty,link=/tmp/vmodem1,echo=0,raw tcp4-listen:54321,reuseaddr`
2. *h2*: Open `/tmp/vmodem1` for reading:

   `cat /tmp/vmodem1 > dump`
3. Start Jenkins job.
4. *h1*: Send some data

   `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/vmodem1 bs=1024 count=10`

Results of those operations available [as this gist](https://gist.github.com/bfo/8413e3af5b6d64e66418). As you can see, even though `dd` reported that bytes had been sent, it didn't happen. When I execute *exactly* the same commands, but run `socat` on h1 from terminal instead of Jenkins, I can see zeros printed in both `socat` outputs and the `dump` file has the expected size.

This setup may seem contrived, but I deliberately left just one `socat` command in the Jenkins script to serve as a minimal example.

`socat` version on both hosts: `1.7.2.3` - default Ubuntu 14.04.
Jenkins version: `1.607`

There must be something different about Jenkins shell environment compared to the regular interactive shell, but why does it break `socat`? Also, if someone knows any other way of establishing such serial connection over the network, I'd greatly appreciate any advice.